# How to use PackageManager canRequestPackageInstalls in Android Oreo?

Tags: android

In my app Manifest I have declared the use of the permission:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

and in my code I check if my app can install from unknown sources:

```
    public void reinstallApp(Activity activity, String pathname, int request_code)
    {
        if (activity.getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls())
        {
            try
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(pathname)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                activity.startActivityForResult(intent, request_code);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LogUtilities.show(this, e);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            activity.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES).setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", activity.getPackageName()))));
        }
    }
```

but the "activity.getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()" is always returning "false", even if I check the allow install from unknow sources in the selection activity.

What's the issue?

Answer (score 23):

You've to ask for permission first. For that you've to call install permission from unknown sources. I got the answer by just rearranging your code.

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            if (!getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES).setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getPackageName()))), 1234);
            } else {
                callInstallProcess();
            }
        } else {
            callInstallProcess();
        }
```

The above code will be in your onCreate() . The you can verify the result.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1234 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()) {
            callInstallProcess();
        }
    } else {
        //give the error
    }
}
```

Where your installation is happening in callInstallProcess();

```
        try
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(pathname)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, request_code);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogUtilities.show(this, e);
        }
```

Don't forget to give permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

Comment: When I use your callInstallProcess() method I get the exception: `exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()`. I think this is because the .apk file is contained in my application, and somehow the other activity cannot access my files.

Comment: NOTE: if in fragment replace startActivityForResult(...) with getActivity(). startActivityForResult(...) to get the good requestCode in onActivityResult

Comment: @ZdravkoDonev FileProvider is what u need.

Comment: When i call `getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()` i get `Java.Lang.SecurityException: 'Need to declare android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES to call this api'`

Answer (score 5):

As stated [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#canRequestPackageInstalls()), for `getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()` to work correctly, you have to declare this permission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml, as you already did, and - most likely the cause of your problem - **declare the `targetSdkVersion` in your build.gradle or AndroidManifest.xml to be 26 or higher** (in other words, your app has to target Android Oreo or above).

Otherwise this method will always return `false`, even if the user granted the permission.

Comment: I was working with an old project, targetSdkVersion did the trick!

Comment: same. targetSdkVersion saved me