# ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES: startActivityForResult() or startActivity()?

Tags: java, android, start-activity, startactivityforresult, android-8.1-oreo

I'm following these tree examples where is showed how request permission to install an app from an unknown source:

1. [How to manage installation from Unknown Sources in Android Oreo?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49828751/13342579)
2. [How to use PackageManager canRequestPackageInstalls in Android Oreo?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48283220/13342579)
3. [Android 8 unknown source app installation](https://www.programmersought.com/article/2255502411/)

When i tested with `startActivityForResult()`, `onActivityResult()` never was called when i enable or disable (on switch widget).

Then my doubt is: `startActvity()` or `startActivityForResult()`? if `startActivityForResult()`, show me how this can works correctly please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation for `ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES) says: "Output: nothing". Hence, use `startActivity()`, not `startActivityForResult()`.